# Show that a specific combination of reciprocals of positive definite matrices must be positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that for any given dimension $n$ there exists a $\lambda > 0$ such that if $n\times n$ symmetric matrices $A,B,C$ are positive definite then
$$
 (\lambda(B+A))^{-1} - (\lambda(B+2A))^{-1}+(C+2B+3A)^{-1} - (C+2B+2A)^{-1} 
$$ 
must also be positive definite.

To clarify, the set of working values of $\lambda$ might depend on $n$; I suspect that for any given $n$ there exists some $\lambda_\max(n) > 0$ such that the above statement holds whenever $\lambda < \lambda_\max(n)$.

This problem is suggested by question 1142459, which fixes on $\lambda = 2$ (and talks about matrices $\{X,B,A\}$ with $\{X-B, B-A, A\}$ positive definite where my statement uses $\{A+B+C,A+B,A\}$).

In the answer to that problem, it is demonstrated (by example) that $\lambda = 2$ does not work for $2 \times 2$ matrices.

For $n = 1$ it is easy to see that   $\lambda_\max(1) = 3$.

For $n=2$ the example in the answer mentioned above gives a non-positive definite sum when $\lambda = 2$, so it shows that $\lambda_\max(2) < 2$.  The example provided does not eliminate $\lambda = 1.8$, however. I think I have a proof that $\lambda\max(1) \geq 1$ but it involves some horrid algebra with the matrix elements and could thus easily contain an error.

Ideally, one could say how $\lambda_\max(n)$ falls with increasing $n$, but I'd settle for a proof that  $\forall n>0: \lambda_\max(n) > 0$.